# Unable to initialize main class Ejemplo1

Tags: java

Es un programa asignado por un profesor el cual solo decía que implementara el código y me da el error del titulo, en algunos IDE me dice que le segundo import no existe.

He buscado el error en todas partes pero no encuentro la solucion.

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.awt.*;

public class Ejemplo1 {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws InterruptedExcecption
    {
    
        System.out.println("Comienza main()...");
        Circulo c = new Circulo(2.0, 2.0, 4.0);
        System.out.println("Radio = " + c.r + " unidades.");
        System.out.println("Centro = (" + c.x + "," + c.y + ") unidades.");
        Circulo c1 = new Circulo(1.0, 1.0, 2.0);
        Circulo c2 = new Circulo(0.0, 0.0, 3.0);
        c = c1.elMayor(c2);
        System.out.println("El mayor radio es " + c.r + ".");
        c = new Circulo(); // c.r = 0.0;
        c = Circulo.elMayor(c1, c2);
        System.out.println("El mayor radio es " + c.r + ".");

        VentanaCerrable ventana =
            new VentanaCerrable("Ventana abierta al mundo...");
        ArrayList v = new ArrayList();

        CirculoGrafico cg1 = new CirculoGrafico(200, 200, 100, Color.red);
        CirculoGrafico cg2 = new CirculoGrafico(300, 200, 100, Color.blue);
        RectanguloGrafico rg = new
            RectanguloGrafico(50, 50, 450, 350, Color.green);

            v.add(cg1);
            v.add(cg2);
            v.add(rg);

            PanelDibujo mipanel = new PanelDibujo(v);
            ventana.add(mipanel);
            ventana.setSize(500, 400);
            System.out.println("Termina main()...");

    }// fin de main()
}// fin de class Ejemplo1
```

Comment: LIsto, ya lo edite.

Comment: no estas importando la libreria del arraylist

Comment: La importe y aun así no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error de tipeo en "InterruptedExcecption" la forma correcta es "InterruptedException", ese tipo de error el IDE Eclipse da un warning al intentar ejecutar y subraya en rojo.

> public static void main(String[] arg) throws InterruptedExcecption

Si aún así lo ejecutas en Eclipse muestra lo siguiente por consola que es un error indicando que no encuentra la clase (la que está mal escrita).

> Error: Unable to initialize main class stack.Ejemplo1
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: InterruptedExcecption

Answer (score -2):

El args no es el que lleva [] si no el String.

En la linea 6:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
```

Comment: En teoría **si** *String* debería ser quien lleve los corchetes pero ya sea que lo ponga antes o después en java debería correr de todas formas, no parece ser el error que presenta OP en su código. ;)

Comment: Asíe es, ya lo intente y sigue igual.